# React fetch data to state returning old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

After fetching the data when I am trying to update a state variable it is saving the old data. On first click it is saving undefined when the data is actually 1. On next click when the data retrieved is 2 the state variable is saving 1. The data is returning only one element like [{QuestId:1}]. The data is saving correctly and responding back newly created recordid from the server.

```js
const [newqid, setNewQid] = useState();

fetch("http://testapi/quest", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    ExId: exid,
    Quest: quest,
  }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (data) => {
      setNewQid(data[0].QuestId);
      console.log("Newqid " + newqid);
    },
    (error) => {
      alert("Failed" + error);
    },
  );
```

Comment: If you weren't needlessly logging data you wouldn't even think there was an issue

Comment: It may seem this way because of the logs but it actually is updating the state correctly. you just need to log it in the correct way which is to use a use effect. If you put your console lo in a use effect with newOid (not set) as the dependency then try it again and watch how the console logs are not correct.  I could explain more but essentially its the way useState and set state works

Comment: ... or don't needlessly log data at all, just use it as intended in your app